# Accessing Foreign Key Values

Tags: django, angular

So here is my two models Offre and Recruteur:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Recruteur(models.Model):          
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Recruteur: {}".format(self.name)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Offre(models.Model):          
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0)
    idRecruteur = models.ForeignKey(Recruteur, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Offre: {}".format(self.title)
```

I want to access the Recruteur's name from the Offre's foreign key,
I simply thought of this solution but it doesnt work:
component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-9">
               {{item.idRecruteur.name }} 
            </div>            
    </div>
```

and component.ts:

```
items: any[] = [];
  constructor(private myService:MyServiceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getAllOffres()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          const myArray = [];
          for (let key in data) {
              myArray.push(data[key]);
              console.log(data);
          }
          this.items = myArray;
        }
      );

  }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a question about foreign key values at all.

You seem to be trying to iterate over an Angular variable using Django template language. This can't possibly work; the template tags are evaluated on the server, before the HTML is produced and set to the browser. There is no way the Angular code can affect the evaluation of the Django tags.